# How do I remove the numbering at the end of each line?

Tags: equations, numbering

This code

```
\begin{align}
y'' & =\frac{-4[ \sin(2x)(3+2y)+\cos(2x)y']}{(3+2y)^2} \\
& = ... \\
& = \frac{-4[ \sin(2x)(3+2y)^2+2\cos^2(2x)]}{(3+2y)^3}=:f_x \\
\end{align}
```

produces this output

[image]

However, I do not want the numbers at the end of each line in the code to exist. How do I remove them? I'm guessing it has something to do with the packages I've used? Here are most of them if they're helpful (I've excluded some matlab formatting code because I don't think it influences)

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
%matlab
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\pagenumbering{gobble}


\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{extarrows}
```

Comment: Have you tried align*?

Comment: @cmhughes Many thanks

Comment: You can remove some (eg. all but one) equation numbers using \notag.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related.

Comment: The difference between starred and non-starred math environments is documented in the `amsmath` users guide:  `texdoc amsldoc`.  You might find this instructive.